# What is the best way to remove rare words from a large text?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

The dataset contains 2.14M words
The following is my code.

```
uni = get_unique(ds) #to get all unique words

c = Counter(uni) #using counter from Collections to create a dictionary
v = list(c.values()) #dict value
ky = list(c.keys()) #dicks keys


junk = [] #indexes of rare words (words that appear less than 20 times)
num = 0 #the number words that appear more than 20 times 
for i in range(len(v)):
    if(v[i] >= 20):
        num += 1
    else:
        junk.append(i)

rare_words = []

for i in junk:
    rare_words.append(ky[i]) #selecting rare words from the keys
```

A function to remove the rare words

```
def remove_jnk(dataset,rare_words):
    ds = []
    for i in dataset:
        repl_wrd = " "
        res = " ".join([repl_wrd if idx in rare_words else idx for idx in i[0].split()])
        ds.append([res]) 
    return ds

ds = remove_jnk(ds, rare_words)
```

**this is too slow and it's taking hours to run**

Comment: Mind if I ask, did you find any solution, do you need any further help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try importing a library suck as `NLTK` and do something like:

```
import nltk
tokens = [] #your word list

freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
```

`FreqDist()` is used to get the distribution of the terms in the corpus, selecting the rarest one into a list

```
rarewords = freq_dist.keys()[-5:]

after_rare_words = [ word for word in token not in rarewords]
```